# HTTP Request waiting for a task to get complete

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to REST APIS and I am trying to build a local memory Cache and writing REST APIS using java and spring framework to get and retrieve data below is the detailed description of what I want to achieve:

```
- Building the REST API to store key-value in local memory cache
- API must have 2 endpoints following specification below
     • /cache/add (This must store unique key only (existing key must be ignored), This will return true if the element was successfully added )
     •/cache/take (This method retrieves and removes the most recently added element from the cache and waits if necessary until an element becomes available)
```

I am not able to figure out how to implement the /cache/take method. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, What does the title of this question has to do with the description? Also, do you need help to develop REST APIs using `Spring`?

Answer (score 5):

for your first requirement *Building the REST API to store key-value in local memory cache* I've used a linkedHashMap as it'll store your key value pairs, and since it is static you could use it as a localcache

for second requirement created two end points one is storing value in linkedHashMap and other one is removing the last entry you entered in linkedHashMap, One way to get last entry of a LinkedHashMap is to use "toArray" method of Set interface. that's what I did, you could have a better approach, this answer could be improved

```
@RestController
public class CacheController {

private static LinkedHashMap<String, String> localCache = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

@RequestMapping(value = { "/cache/add" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Boolean cacheAdd(@RequestParam(value = "key", required = true) String key, @RequestParam(value = "value", required = true) String value) {
    if (localCache.containsKey(key)) {
        return false;
    }
    localCache.put(key, value);
    return true;
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/cache/take" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String cacheTake() {
    Set<Entry<String, String>> mapValues = localCache.entrySet();
    int maplength = mapValues.size();
    Entry<String, String>[] cacheArray = new Entry[maplength];
    mapValues.toArray(cacheArray);
    System.out.print("Last Key:" + cacheArray[maplength - 1].getKey());
    System.out.println(" Last Value:" + cacheArray[maplength - 1].getValue());
    localCache.remove(cacheArray[maplength - 1].getKey());
    return cacheArray[maplength - 1].getValue();
}

}
```